# Mysql workbench EER diagram line style field-to-field

Tags: mysql-workbench

Currently I see 90deg-based table-to-table lines. Is there any way to change it to straight field-to-field lines?

Now it looks like this.

[image]

I googled this image. So its probably possible change line style. Or its differs by OS or workbench version(maybe this is old feature?)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried it on Workbench 6.0 (for Mac) and found it under **Model » Relationship Notation » Connect to Columns** menu. I believe it won't diff much between different OSs.

[image]

Comment: thx, works in linux too. I didnt expected to find it there. I only searched in diagram properties